# How to prevent non-images from being uploaded

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I am building a webapp on google app engine with python and I have the following code that allows users to upload an image but if someone uploads something that is not an image the code breaks down because I am trying to create an image url out of the data and it of course does not accept anything that is not an image file.  Basically I wanted to know if there is a simple way to prevent files that are not image files from being uploaded.

```
class RecordPage(BlogHandler):
    def get(self, keyid, title):
        record = individual_record_cache(keyid)
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload/%s' % (keyid))
        photos = []
        for blobRef in record.blobRefs:
            photos.append(images.get_serving_url(blobRef, size=None, crop=False, secure_url=None))

        global visits
        user = users.get_current_user()
        logout = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)       
        self.render("recordpermalink.html", user=user, logout=logout, record=record, visits=visits, photos=photos, upload_url=upload_url, keyid=keyid)

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self, record_id):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        blobRef = blob_info.key()
        record = Record.get_by_id(int(record_id))
        record.blobRefs.append(blobRef)
        record.put()
        individual_record_cache(record_id, True)
        record_cache(True)
        profile_record_cache(True)
        self.redirect('/record/%s/%s' % (record_id, record.title))
```

Comment: Can you add specific detail to "all hell breaks loose in the error codes"?

Answer (score 3):

1. If you installed a upload handler then you can not prevent blobs being uploaded, because your handler is only called after blob is already in the blobstore. However, you can inspect the blob and delete it.
2. After blob is uploaded you can check if it's an image using `ImageService`:

   ```
   Image image = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromBlob(blobKey);
   try {
       image.getFormat();
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
       // wrong image data - blob uploaded was not an image -> delete it
   }
   ```

Comment: I suppose this is the same as the Images API in Python? I see how to check the format but how do I create an image from a blobkey with python?  I can't seem to find that in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know what's an image until it's uploaded, or at least the first few bytes of it are uploaded.

If you want to trust the file extension on the filename, you can just do something like this:

```
import mimetypes
blob_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(blob_info.filename)[0]
# or just: blob_mimetype = blob_info.content_type
if not blob_mimetype.startswith('image/'):
    self.error(400)
```

Whatever "breaking down" the code is doing, this will probably not protect you if someone wants to upload an invalid image or if they rename the file to have a different file extension before uploading. It will only help if you're trying to keep most good-faith users from seeing errors.

Ideally, if the "code breaking down" means getting an exception from the handler code, you can just wrap it in a try/except and handle it appropriately. That's the more pythonic approach and doesn't do extra up-front computation or try to be smarter than it has to.

Answer (score 2):

You should use two forms of checking (both after the upload is completed, however). First, MIME type: make sure it starts with "image/*". Second, try to read the image with an image handler:

```
from PIL import Image
class UploadHandler(BaseUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
    try:
        upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
        # also check mime type here
        i = Image.open(upload.open()) # open it with PIL
        w, h = i.size # make sure you can read its size
    except:
        # error stuff here, probably means it's not an image
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to identify the file. Just let the upload complete, and then use their command line tool `identify` to see if it is actually an image.

[Here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) is the link to the `identify` command line documentation. However, I wouldn't recommend you use the command like that. You should probably use a wrapper like PythonMagick.

**Edit: After looking at your question again, you are using GAE. I only have experience with the Java side of GAE, but I would assume that since Java GAE doesn't really have a lot of image handling APIs, the Python side wouldn't either. The best solution I can think of off of the top of my head is to farm off that work to a VPS like EC2.**

Comment: There are native image processing libraries that run on GAE and allow images to be dynamically identified and manipulated. No need to use an external service.